# Ошибка в Selenium: Unable to locate element Python Selenium

Tags: python, парсер, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Нужно, чтобы в обведенное окошко вбивались номера. Сайт открывается, но ячейка не ищется.

Selenium, webdriver работают нормально - проверила с другим сайтом. Здесь же проблема в коде элемента. Попробовала поиск через class (код ниже), но выдаётся ошибка, хотя этот класс есть в html-коде элемента.

Сайт https://pub.fsa.gov.ru/rds/declaration [image: Окошко слева]
HTML элемента с окошком

```html
<div _ngcontent-c14=""><label _ngcontent-c14="">Номер декларации о соответствии</label><div _ngcontent-c14="" class="fgis-selectbox-wrapper"><fgis-text _ngcontent-c14="" _nghost-c27="" class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid"><input _ngcontent-c27="" class="checkbox__input ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid" autofocus=""><div _ngcontent-c27="" class="checkbox__view"></div></fgis-text></div><label _ngcontent-c14="">Дата регистрации декларации</label><br _ngcontent-c14=""><fgis-date-range _ngcontent-c14="" _nghost-c28="" class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid"><div _ngcontent-c28="" class="date-range"><!----><!----><fgis-calendar _ngcontent-c28="" _nghost-c32="" class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid ng-star-inserted"><div _ngcontent-c32="" class="calendar-container"><p-calendar _ngcontent-c32="" class="ng-tns-c33-0 ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid"><span class="ng-tns-c33-0 ui-calendar"><!----><input autocomplete="off" type="text" class="ng-tns-c33-0 hidden ui-inputtext ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ng-star-inserted" placeholder=""><!----><!----><!----></span></p-calendar><div _ngcontent-c32="" class="input-div"><input _ngcontent-c32="" class="form-control small-input ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid" type="text"></div></div></fgis-calendar><!----><span _ngcontent-c28="" class="date-range__separator">-</span><!----><!----><fgis-calendar _ngcontent-c28="" _nghost-c32="" class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid ng-star-inserted"><div _ngcontent-c32="" class="calendar-container"><p-calendar _ngcontent-c32="" class="ng-tns-c33-1 ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid"><span class="ng-tns-c33-1 ui-calendar"><!----><input autocomplete="off" type="text" class="ng-tns-c33-1 hidden ui-inputtext ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ng-star-inserted" placeholder=""><!----><!----><!----></span></p-calendar><div _ngcontent-c32="" class="input-div"><input _ngcontent-c32="" class="form-control small-input ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid" type="text"></div></div></fgis-calendar><!----></div></fgis-date-range><label _ngcontent-c14="">Дата окончания действия декларации</label><br _ngcontent-c14=""><fgis-date-range _ngcontent-c14="" _nghost-c28="" class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid"><div _ngcontent-c28="" class="date-range"><!----><!----><fgis-calendar _ngcontent-c28="" _nghost-c32="" class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid ng-star-inserted"><div _ngcontent-c32="" class="calendar-container"><p-calendar _ngcontent-c32="" class="ng-tns-c33-2 ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid"><span class="ng-tns-c33-2 ui-calendar"><!----><input autocomplete="off" type="text" class="ng-tns-c33-2 hidden ui-inputtext ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ng-star-inserted" placeholder=""><!----><!----><!----></span></p-calendar><div _ngcontent-c32="" class="input-div"><input _ngcontent-c32="" class="form-control small-input ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid" type="text"></div></div></fgis-calendar><!----><span _ngcontent-c28="" class="date-range__separator">-</span><!----><!----><fgis-calendar _ngcontent-c28="" _nghost-c32="" class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid ng-star-inserted"><div _ngcontent-c32="" class="calendar-container"><p-calendar _ngcontent-c32="" class="ng-tns-c33-3 ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid"><span class="ng-tns-c33-3 ui-calendar"><!----><input autocomplete="off" type="text" class="ng-tns-c33-3 hidden ui-inputtext ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ng-star-inserted" placeholder=""><!----><!----><!----></span></p-calendar><div _ngcontent-c32="" class="input-div"><input _ngcontent-c32="" class="form-control small-input ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid" type="text"></div></div></fgis-calendar><!----></div></fgis-date-range><label _ngcontent-c14="">Статус</label><div _ngcontent-c14="" class="fgis-selectbox-wrapper"><fgis-selectbox _ngcontent-c14="" _nghost-c22="" class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid"><!----><!----><!----><!----><fgis-chips _ngcontent-c22="" _nghost-c25="" class="ng-star-inserted"><!----></fgis-chips><div _ngcontent-c22="" class="fgis-selectbox__below" tabindex="0"><div _ngcontent-c22="" class="fgis-selectbox__single"><!----><!----><!----><!----><!----><div _ngcontent-c22="" class="fgis-selectbox__single-placeholder ng-star-inserted">  </div><!----><!----><div _ngcontent-c22="" class="fgis-selectbox__single-toggle ng-star-inserted"><i _ngcontent-c22="" aria-hidden="true"></i></div></div></div></fgis-selectbox></div><label _ngcontent-c14="">Тип декларации</label><div _ngcontent-c14="" class="fgis-selectbox-wrapper"><fgis-selectbox _ngcontent-c14="" _nghost-c22="" class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid"><!----><!----><!----><!----><fgis-chips _ngcontent-c22="" _nghost-c25="" class="ng-star-inserted"><!----></fgis-chips><div _ngcontent-c22="" class="fgis-selectbox__below" tabindex="0"><div _ngcontent-c22="" class="fgis-selectbox__single"><!----><!----><!----><!----><!----><div _ngcontent-c22="" class="fgis-selectbox__single-placeholder ng-star-inserted">  </div><!----><!----><div _ngcontent-c22="" class="fgis-selectbox__single-toggle ng-star-inserted"><i _ngcontent-c22="" aria-hidden="true"></i></div></div></div></fgis-selectbox></div><label _ngcontent-c14="">Тип объекта декларирования</label><div _ngcontent-c14="" class="fgis-selectbox-wrapper"><fgis-selectbox _ngcontent-c14="" _nghost-c22="" class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid"><!----><!----><!----><!----><fgis-chips _ngcontent-c22="" _nghost-c25="" class="ng-star-inserted"><!----></fgis-chips><div _ngcontent-c22="" class="fgis-selectbox__below" tabindex="0"><div _ngcontent-c22="" class="fgis-selectbox__single"><!----><!----><!----><!----><!----><div _ngcontent-c22="" class="fgis-selectbox__single-placeholder ng-star-inserted">  </div><!----><!----><div _ngcontent-c22="" class="fgis-selectbox__single-toggle ng-star-inserted"><i _ngcontent-c22="" aria-hidden="true"></i></div></div></div></fgis-selectbox></div><label _ngcontent-c14="">Происхождение продукции</label><div _ngcontent-c14="" class="fgis-selectbox-wrapper"><fgis-selectbox _ngcontent-c14="" _nghost-c22="" class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid"><!----><!----><!----><!----><fgis-chips _ngcontent-c22="" _nghost-c25="" class="ng-star-inserted"><!----></fgis-chips><div _ngcontent-c22="" class="fgis-selectbox__below" tabindex="0"><div _ngcontent-c22="" class="fgis-selectbox__single"><!----><!----><!----><!----><!----><div _ngcontent-c22="" class="fgis-selectbox__single-placeholder ng-star-inserted">  </div><!----><!----><div _ngcontent-c22="" class="fgis-selectbox__single-toggle ng-star-inserted"><i _ngcontent-c22="" aria-hidden="true"></i></div></div></div></fgis-selectbox></div><label _ngcontent-c14="">Группы продукции РФ</label><div _ngcontent-c14="" class="fgis-selectbox-wrapper"><fgis-selectbox-tree _ngcontent-c14="" _nghost-c29="" class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid"><!----><!----><!----><fgis-chips _ngcontent-c29="" _nghost-c25="" class="ng-star-inserted"><!----></fgis-chips><div _ngcontent-c29="" class="fgis-selectbox__below" tabindex="0"><div _ngcontent-c29="" class="fgis-selectbox__single"><div _ngcontent-c29="" class="fgis-selectbox__single-value" title="">  </div><!----><div _ngcontent-c29="" class="fgis-selectbox__single-toggle fgis-selectbox__single-toggle_open_down"></div></div></div></fgis-selectbox-tree></div><label _ngcontent-c14="">Группы продукции ЕАЭС</label><div _ngcontent-c14="" class="fgis-selectbox-wrapper"><fgis-selectbox-tree _ngcontent-c14="" _nghost-c29="" class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid"><!----><!----><!----><fgis-chips _ngcontent-c29="" _nghost-c25="" class="ng-star-inserted"><!----></fgis-chips><div _ngcontent-c29="" class="fgis-selectbox__below" tabindex="0"><div _ngcontent-c29="" class="fgis-selectbox__single"><div _ngcontent-c29="" class="fgis-selectbox__single-value" title="">  </div><!----><div _ngcontent-c29="" class="fgis-selectbox__single-toggle fgis-selectbox__single-toggle_open_down"></div></div></div></fgis-selectbox-tree></div><label _ngcontent-c14="">Единый перечень продукции ЕАЭС</label><div _ngcontent-c14="" class="fgis-selectbox-wrapper"><fgis-selectbox-tree _ngcontent-c14="" _nghost-c29="" class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid"><!----><!----><!----><fgis-chips _ngcontent-c29="" _nghost-c25="" class="ng-star-inserted"><!----></fgis-chips><div _ngcontent-c29="" class="fgis-selectbox__below" tabindex="0"><div _ngcontent-c29="" class="fgis-selectbox__single"><div _ngcontent-c29="" class="fgis-selectbox__single-value" title="">  </div><!----><div _ngcontent-c29="" class="fgis-selectbox__single-toggle fgis-selectbox__single-toggle_open_down"></div></div></div></fgis-selectbox-tree></div><label _ngcontent-c14="">Единый перечень продукции РФ</label><div _ngcontent-c14="" class="fgis-selectbox-wrapper"><fgis-selectbox-tree _ngcontent-c14="" _nghost-c29="" class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid"><!----><!----><!----><fgis-chips _ngcontent-c29="" _nghost-c25="" class="ng-star-inserted"><!----></fgis-chips><div _ngcontent-c29="" class="fgis-selectbox__below" tabindex="0"><div _ngcontent-c29="" class="fgis-selectbox__single"><div _ngcontent-c29="" class="fgis-selectbox__single-value" title="">  </div><!----><div _ngcontent-c29="" class="fgis-selectbox__single-toggle fgis-selectbox__single-toggle_open_down"></div></div></div></fgis-selectbox-tree></div><!----><label _ngcontent-c14="">Технический регламент</label><div _ngcontent-c14="" class="fgis-selectbox-wrapper"><fgis-selectbox _ngcontent-c14="" _nghost-c22="" class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid"><!----><!----><!----><!----><fgis-chips _ngcontent-c22="" _nghost-c25="" class="ng-star-inserted"><!----></fgis-chips><div _ngcontent-c22="" class="fgis-selectbox__below" tabindex="0"><div _ngcontent-c22="" class="fgis-selectbox__single"><!----><!----><!----><!----><!----><div _ngcontent-c22="" class="fgis-selectbox__single-placeholder ng-star-inserted">  </div><!----><!----><div _ngcontent-c22="" class="fgis-selectbox__single-toggle ng-star-inserted"><i _ngcontent-c22="" aria-hidden="true"></i></div></div></div></fgis-selectbox></div><label _ngcontent-c14="">Вид заявителя</label><div _ngcontent-c14="" class="fgis-selectbox-wrapper"><fgis-selectbox _ngcontent-c14="" _nghost-c22="" class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid"><!----><!----><!----><!----><fgis-chips _ngcontent-c22="" _nghost-c25="" class="ng-star-inserted"><!----></fgis-chips><div _ngcontent-c22="" class="fgis-selectbox__below" tabindex="0"><div _ngcontent-c22="" class="fgis-selectbox__single"><!----><!----><!----><!----><!----><div _ngcontent-c22="" class="fgis-selectbox__single-placeholder ng-star-inserted">  </div><!----><!----><div _ngcontent-c22="" class="fgis-selectbox__single-toggle ng-star-inserted"><i _ngcontent-c22="" aria-hidden="true"></i></div></div></div></fgis-selectbox></div><!----></div>
```

Мой код

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path = 'C:\geckodriver.exe')
browser.get('https://pub.fsa.gov.ru/rds/declaration')

content = browser.find_element_by_class_name('checkbox__view')
content.send_keys('ЕАЭС N RU Д-TR.РА01.А.44855/19')
```

Выдаётся ошибка

```
Message: Unable to locate element: .checkbox__input ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid
```

Затем я попробовала добавить сон

```
import time 
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path = 'C:\geckodriver.exe')
browser.get('https://pub.fsa.gov.ru/rds/declaration')
time.sleep(6)

content = browser.find_element_by_class_name('checkbox__view')
content.send_keys('ЕАЭС N RU Д-TR.РА01.А.44855/19')
```

Ошибка

```
Message: Element <div class="checkbox__view"> is not reachable by keyboard
```

Как исправить запрос, чтобы в окошко с номером можно было вводить свои запросы дистанционно?

Answer (score 0):

Доброе время суток.

Тут на поверхности 2 выхода:

1) найти родительский элемент и внутри него найти уже требуемый (напрмер по тегу "input")

2) найти элемент по Xpath (не самый лучший вариант, но все же вариант, работает надежно, но возможно не долговечно, как повезет (пока сайт не перепилят)).

P.S. ваша ошибка в том, что вы пытаетесь добавить текст в Label, а нужно в Input

Вот его Xpath на всякий случай:

```
/html/body/fgis-root/div/fgis-rds-declaration-table-view/div/fgis-rds-declaration-advanced-search/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/fgis-text/input
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

У вас 2 проблемы:

- Ожидание загрузки страницы, чтобы появился элемент. Предлагаю решить это через неявное ожидание: `implicitly_wait`
- Поиск элемента для ввода. Посмотрел и по-моему самый простой вариант найти тот элемент -- поиск тега `input` у которого есть атрибут `_ngcontent-c27`, в css-селекторе это будет: `input[_ngcontent-c27]`

[Пример:](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/42fc02cce76b5119d3238cd28954f35701ce8fb5/selenium__examples/pub_fsa_gov_ru__rds__declaration.py#L11)

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='C:\geckodriver.exe')
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.get('https://pub.fsa.gov.ru/rds/declaration')

content = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('input[_ngcontent-c27]')
content.send_keys('ЕАЭС N RU Д-TR.РА01.А.44855/19')
```

Comment: Заработало, спасибо!

Comment: @AnnaBuylova, [чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ и отметьте его как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) :)